# Action creators not showing in "this.props" with redux-form 6.0.0-rc.3

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

When I used redux-form 5.3.1 I was able to access my action creators. But as I needed Material-UI, I updated it to 6.0.0-rc.3.

Changes from 5.3.1 to 6.0.0:

- Removed fields from render():

`const { handleSubmit, fields: { email, password, passwordConfirm }} = this.props;`

- Removed errors validation from under inputs:

`{email.touched && email.error && <div className="error">{email.error}</div>}`

- Removed fields array from export default:

`export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signup',
  fields: ['email', 'password', 'passwordConfirm'],
  validate
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);`

- Added wrappers for Material-UI components:

`import { renderTextField, renderCheckbox, renderSelectField, renderDatePicker } from '../material-ui-wrapper';`

Code:

**1 - console.log(this.props) logs no action creator** - should log signupUser function

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

import { renderTextField } from '../material-ui-wrapper';

import {Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';

class Signup extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.signupUser(formProps);
  }

  renderAlert() {
    if (this.props.errorMessage) {
      return (
        <div className="error">
          {this.props.errorMessage}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting } = this.props;
    return (
      <form id="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <Card>
          <CardHeader title="Cadastre-se"/>
          <CardText>
            <Field name="email" component={renderTextField} label={"Email"} fieldType="text"/>
            <Field name="password" component={renderTextField} label={"Senha"} fieldType="password"/>
            <Field name="passwordConfirm" component={renderTextField} label={"Confirmação de senha"} fieldType="password"/>
            {this.renderAlert()}
          </CardText>
          <CardActions>
            <FlatButton type="submit" label="Criar!"/>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function validate(formProps) {
  const errors = {};

  if (!formProps.email || !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(formProps.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Por favor, informe um email válido';
  }

  if (formProps.password !== formProps.passwordConfirm) {
    errors.password = 'Senhas devem ser iguais.';
  }

  if (!formProps.password) {
    errors.password = 'Por favor, informe uma senha.';
  }

  if (!formProps.passwordConfirm) {
    errors.passwordConfirm = 'Por favor, confirme a sua senha.';
  }

  return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { errorMessage: state.auth.error };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signup',
  validate
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);
```

**EDIT**

Changed:

`export default reduxForm({
      form: 'signup',
      validate
    }, mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);`

To:

`Signup = reduxForm({
    form: 'signup',
    validate
})(Signup);
export default Signup = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);`

It **worked**. Is it the most correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signup',
  validate
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);
```

Use:

```
Signup = reduxForm({
form: 'signup',
validate})(Signup);

export default Signup = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);
```

**PS: Might be a work around**

Comment: oh, boy... api regression, not backwards compatible, it smells awful from a distance

Comment: @IgorDonin OP was working thru a major version (v5 -> v6), so this is acceptable from semver point of view.

Answer (score 3):

You can use compose like follow

```
import { compose } from 'redux'
....
export default compose(
    reduxForm({
      form: 'survey',
    }),
    connect(mapStateToProps, actions)
)(Signup)
```

Comment: Of course should `import { connect } from 'react-redux'`.

Answer (score 0):

> To get those values into your redux-form-decorated component, you will
>   need to connect() to the Redux state yourself and map from the data
>   reducer to the initialValues prop.

http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/

Answer (score 0):

> You can use constructor to bind method with your existing props.
>   you do not need to pass actions and initial state.

```
class Signup extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
   }

   handleSubmit(formProps) {
     console.log(this.props);
     this.props.signupUser(formProps);
  }
  render() {

  const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting } = this.props;

  return (

  <form id="form" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
    <Card>
      <CardHeader title="Cadastre-se"/>
      <CardText>
        <Field name="email" component={renderTextField} label={"Email"} fieldType="text"/>
        <Field name="password" component={renderTextField} label={"Senha"} fieldType="password"/>
        <Field name="passwordConfirm" component={renderTextField} label={"Confirmação de senha"} fieldType="password"/>
       </CardText>
        <CardActions>
          <FlatButton type="submit" label="Criar!"/>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </form>
   );
  }
 }
}
Signup = reduxForm({
 form: 'signup',
 validate})(Signup);

export default Signup = connect()(Signup);
```